# What is ${0} = 1 in php

Tags: php

Can someone explain what is happening on this assignment?
**Where can i read the manual?**

```
${0} = 1;
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: I'm getting `Notice: Undefined variable: 0 in test.php on line 1`

Comment: Try it (everything works)- such code is used in reliable project
error_reporting(E_ALL);
${0} = 1;
var_dump(${0});

Comment: updated my answer to put the most relevant part to your question at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called `Variable Variables`. Although this is not a good usage because it manages to define a variable called `${0}`.

You can read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Technically in this particular case it's not a variable variable. Edit: Just saw you mentioned that :P

Comment: Yes, you're right. But that is the feature that allow this kind of construct to be possible in PHP. Upvoted your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

`${0}` in this particular case is a way to name a variable with a number, but you would have to be sure to call the variable the same way because `$0` will not work.

More examples:

```
${'foo'} = 'bar';

echo $foo;
```

will echo `bar` because `${'foo'} =` and `$foo =` are essentially the same.

this allows you to perform string operations in your variable definition: like:

```
$string = 'foobar';

${str_replace('foo','bar',$string)} = 'foofoo';

echo $barbar;
```

will echo `foofoo`

Also, using curly braces around variables in a parsed string will ensure that the parser doesn't get confused. For example:

```
$car = "Buick";

echo "The cars were all $cars"; // won't work because it will look for variable $cars

echo "The cars were all {$car}s"; // OR

echo "The cars were all ${car}s"; // will both echo The cars were all Buicks
```

There are more uses for curly braces in variable names, see the link in the other answer to learn more.

Comment: Try it (everything works)- such code is used in reliable project:   

error_reporting(E_ALL);
${0} = 1;
var_dump(${0});

Comment: Yeah I just forgot to call it as `${123}` as well and tried calling `$123`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that curly braces literally mean "evaluate what's inside the curly braces" so, you can squeeze the variable variable creation into one line, like this:

```
<?php
  ${"title_default_" . $title} = "selected";
?>
```

and then, **for example**:

```
<?php
 $title_select = '
    <select name="title">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option $title_default_Mr  value="Mr">Mr</option>
      <option $title_default_Ms  value="Ms">Ms</option>
      <option $title_default_Mrs value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
      <option $title_default_Dr  value="Dr">Dr</option>
    </select>';
echo $title_select;?>
```

You can read more about this http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

**we can play around even more!**

You can't access these with 'normal' global variables, but the curly brace form works as does getting at them via the $GLOBALS superglobal variable! Values are converted to strings which is why 0xFF => '255', etc.

```
${007} = 'Hello Peter'; // $GLOBALS['7']
${0xFF} = 'Hello Peter'; // $GLOBALS['255']
${2 + 2} = 'Hello Peter'; // $GLOBALS['4']
${'Hello Peter'} = 'Hello Peter'; // $GLOBALS['Hello Peter']
${'cats, pet food, dogs'} = 'Hello Peter'; // $GLOBALS['cats, pet food, dogs']
```